# Submitting follow & unfollow with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

okay so the main problem im having is that , im trying post isset to my php file which contains mysqli_query to insert the follower and remove the follower , i have tried it in simple way by making an `<a href="follow.php?action=follow&uid=$userid">follow</a>`  and it worked fine with follow and unfollow , but now im trying to do it without refreshing the page , but somehow its notworking at all. and im new to jquery :).

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT id FROM follow_user WHERE userid='$userid' AND follow_id='$uid'"); 
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)== 1)
{
    echo "<div id='follow$userid' style='display:none'><a href='' class='follow' id='$userid'><span class='btn'style='width:70px;'><b> Follow </b></span></a></div>";

    echo"<div id='remove$userid' ><a href='#' class='remove' id='$userid'><span class='btn btn-info' style='width:70px;'><b> Following </b></span></a></div>";
}
else
{
    echo "<div id='follow$userid'><a href='' class='follow' id='$userid'><span class='btn'style='width:70px;'><b> Follow </b></span></a></div>";

    echo"<div id='remove$userid' style='display:none'><a href='#' class='remove' id='$userid'><span class='btn btn-info' style='width:70px;'><b> Following </b></span></a></div>";
}

?>

jquery

$(function () {
    $(".follow").click(function () {
        var datastring = '?action=follow&uid=' + userid;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "include/follow_user.php",
            data: datastring,
            success: function (html) {}
        });
        $("#follow" + userid).hide();
        $("#remove" + userid).show();
        alert("Yeah!");
        return false;
    });
});

//remove class
$(function () {
    $(".remove").click(function () {
        var datastring = '?action=unfollow&uid=' + userid;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "include/follow_user.php",
            data: datastring,
            success: function (html) {}
        });
        $("#remove" + userid).hide();
        $("#follow" + userid).show();
        alert("Yeah!");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: *What* is not working? That code after the `ajax` function should be **inside** the `success` callback.

Comment: you mean by `$("#follow" + userid).hide();` and alert? the jquery is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for success actions should be **inside** the `success` callback or else they will be called anytime without the conclusion of the request itself. Take a look:

```
$(".follow").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "include/follow_user.php",
        data: {action:"follow", uid: userid},
        success: function (html) {
            $("#follow" + userid).hide();
            $("#remove" + userid).show();
            alert("Yeah!");
        }
    });
});
```

Then in your "follow_user.php" you have to return the process state(e.g. `1` ok - `2` error):

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)== 1)
{
    echo "1";
}
else
{
    echo "2";
}
```

Then in your callback you check it:

```
success: function(data) 
{
    if (data == "1")
    {
        $("#follow" + userid).hide();
        $("#remove" + userid).show();
        alert("Yeah!");
    }
    else 
    {
        alert("Some error occur");
    } 
}
```

Comment: how can i check if ajax is loaded or not?

Comment: @user3499463 Nice! Your code was working, I believe. You just was putting your success codes outside the *callback*. Anyway, in order to watch your ajax requests, use the Developer Tools. All browser have this, but I recomend Chrome's. Just press `F12` and go to Network tab.

Comment: now jquery is giving me succes but not posting to php file :/

Comment: @user3499463 I have change the `data` attribute of your ajax. Then see what I said about dev tools and tell what is going on in your requests.

Comment: now by looking at network tool jquery haven't loaded

Comment: i have modified little bit and now its only post ; follow.php without action=unfollow&uid

Comment: @user3499463 if you have modified, please update your main post with the changes. That ajax should be posting that `data` object. Its equal than [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: no worries bro its worked , just had to add `var userid = $(this).attr("id");`

Comment: @user3499463 nice! Just remember to sanitizer your post values to avoid [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Here's an example](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) of how to do it in PHP.